# How to test a dynamic imported component in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, automated-tests, vuejs3, vitest

This is the component I am trying to test:

```js
<template>
  <component :is="content" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
const route = useRoute()
const content = defineAsyncComponent(() =>
  import(`@/pages/${route.params.path}.md`)
)
</script>
```

I tried to test it in the next way:

```js
import { describe, it, beforeAll, vi } from 'vitest'
import { render } from '@testing-library/vue'

import router from '@/router/index'
vi.mock('@/pages/example.md', () => ({ default: 'Markdown' }))
import PageView from '@/views/Page.vue'

describe('PageView', () => {
  let wrapper
  beforeAll(async () => {
    router.push({ name: 'page', params: { path: 'example' } })
    await router.isReady()

    wrapper = render(PageView, {
      global: { plugins: [router] },
    })
  })

  it('display a markdown file according to params', () => {
   wrapper.getByText('Markdown')
  })
})
```

My component works fine, but in my test it doesn't render anything.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the test output?

Comment: Sure, it cannot find `"Markdown"` in the page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might come from the loading of the component.

```js
import {vi} from 'vitest'
// Your code

it('display a markdown file according to params', () => {
    await vi.dynamicImportSettled()
    wrapper.getByText('Markdown')
  })
```

I found the solution here [Solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/yr9h2d/how_to_unit_test_vue3_components_that_are_both/)